# A generic error occurred in GDI+ JPG Format

Tags: c#

This is my code :

```
SS32.Save(@"D:\O32\ss32" + ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

When i start debugging, i receive this error :

[image: Shot]

Im trying to code a program on c# to take a auto shot from desktop.

Comment: Make sure your application has permission to write at this location.

Comment: What did Google tell you when you searched for this problem? What happened when you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I solve this problem. as you see in that shot this code :

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(@"F:\Imageee");
```

This Directory is code to Drive F and this code :

```
 SS32.Save(@"F:\Imageee\SPii" + ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

by the way, i solve it  by changing `System.Drawing` Directory to exact directory that coded in part 1.

Thanks all